# Number of rectangles containing a point of grid

Tags: math, combinations

I want to know number of rectangles possible in grid that contain a specific point(Not the algo. for calculating all rectangle points).

Eg. let grid be ->

```
11 12 13 14 15

21 22 23 24 25

31 32 33 34 35
```

now let's say we want '11' to be always present inside all the rectangles possible with this grid. So possibles rectangles will be -

```
11

11 12

11 12 13

11 12 13 14

11 12 13 14 15

11    
21

11
21    
31

11 12    
21 22
```

So on... and for this there will be total 15 possible rectangles.

How to calculate total number of such rectangles for a given point in grid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the grid like this:

```
+--+--+--+--+--+
|11|12|13|14|15|
+--+--+--+--+--+
|21|22|23|24|25|
+--+--+--+--+--+
|31|32|33|34|35|
+--+--+--+--+--+
```

Every `+` is a rectangle corner point and every rectangle can be described with two opposing points so that one is the upper left and one is the lower right corner.
If we want to find all rectangles that contain a given field `pq`, we need to find all rectangles whose upper left corner point lies above and to the left of our field and whose lower right corner point lies below and to the right of the field.
All the upper left and all the lower right corner points will yield again two grids:

```
pq = 22
+--+
|11|12 13 14 15
+--+
 21 22 23 24 25
      +--+--+--+
 31 32|33|34|35|
      +--+--+--+
```

The size of the upper left one is easily computed with: `p*q`
The lower right one's size can be computed with: `(r+1-p)*(c+1-q)`
Where `r` is the number of rows and `c` the number of columns (3 and 5 respectively in this case).

In the end the amount of rectangles containing pq is:
`p*q * (r+1-p)*(c+1-q)`

With `pq=11` this would be: `1*1 * (3+1-1)*(5+1-1) = 1 * 3*5 = 15`